# Php division by 0, help needed?

Tags: php

I keep getting division by 0 error in php.

I am currently using the following:

```
$ratio = 1/$rate["rate"];
```

the value $rate["rate"] is 0.827 (a value returned from a feed)

Please can anyone help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this question. Dino is a new user. Please coach him/her by *at least* leaving a comment if you're going to down-vote.

Comment: What type of variable is $rate["rate"]? If is string, maybe instead of a decimal point is used the comma?

Comment: @macek: I've downvoted the question for not being a question. Appending a `?` does not turn "please help" into one. After 32 posts he's not a new user anymore. Let's not upvote low-quality dupes too much, okay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Division by Zero Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451816/php-division-by-zero-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're getting a division by 0 error, `$rate['rate']` is most certainly or *equivalent* to 0. More likely than not, `$rate['rate']` isn't getting set at all, and thusly you're trying to divide by an undefined value which is being cast to 0 for division.

To be sure, do a `var_dump($rate['rate'])` to see what it is.

Whenever you're doing a division operation that depends on a user input, I'd recommend validating the user input before attempting the division.

```
if(is_numeric($rate['rate']) && $rate['rate']!=0){
  $ratio = 1/$rate['rate'];
}
else {
  $ratio = 1;
}
```

[See this code work on tehplayground.com](http://tehplayground.com/#4e39e8290ff0e)

Comment: The try/catch block is not useful, since it will generate a runtime warning, not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $rate['rate'] is not converted to int somewhere along the way.